# Certain python libraries are not loading in my Django application in production, but load fine in local server

Tags: python, django, linux, ubuntu, huggingface-transformers

In my views.py file of my Django application I'm trying to load the 'transformers' library with the following command:

```
from transformers import pipeline
```

This works in my local environment, but on my Linux server at Linode, when I try to load my website, the page tries to load for 5 minutes then I get a Timeout error. I don't understand what is going on, I know I have installed the library correctly. I have also run the same code in the python shell on my server and it loads fine, it's is just that if I load it in my Django views.py file, no page of my website loads.

My server: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, Nanode 1GB: 1 CPU, 25GB Storage, 1GB RAM

Library: transformers==3.0.2

I also have the same problem when I try to load tensorflow. All the other libraries are loading fine, like pytorch and pandas etc. I've been trying to solve this problem since more than a week, I've also changed hosts from GCP to Linode, but it's still the same.

**Edit:** I created a new server and installed everything from scratch and used a virtualenv this time, but still its the same problem. Following are the installed libraries outputted from `pip freeze`:

```
asgiref==3.2.10
certifi==2020.6.20
chardet==3.0.4
click==7.1.2
Django==3.0.7
djangorestframework==3.11.0
filelock==3.0.12
future==0.18.2
idna==2.10
joblib==0.16.0
numpy==1.19.1
packaging==20.4
Pillow==7.2.0
pyparsing==2.4.7
pytz==2020.1
regex==2020.7.14
requests==2.24.0
sacremoses==0.0.43
sentencepiece==0.1.91
six==1.15.0
sqlparse==0.3.1
tokenizers==0.8.1rc1
torch==1.5.1+cpu
torchvision==0.6.1+cpu
tqdm==4.48.0
transformers==3.0.2
urllib3==1.25.10
```

I also know transformers library is installed because if I try to import some library that doesn't exist then I simply get an error, like I should. But in this case it just loads forever and doesn't output any error. This is so bizarre.

Comment: Looks like the problem is on linode. Did you create a virtualenv on linode?

Comment: @VisheshMangla No, haven't created a virtual env. Should I be using virtualenv? I also raised the time limit in the apache.conf file from 300 to 3000, and now after waiting about 10 minutes I get 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: Well, I havent used linode but have used pythonanywhere and heroku. On heroku it auto creates a virtualenv and on pythonanywhere you gotta create one.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sa_kQheCnds

Comment: @VisheshMangla Hey thanks, I will try using running the site on a virtualenv, now and see if it works. However, I followed multiple tutorials about launching a Django site on Linode and none of them used virtualenv. But I will try that now, thanks.

Comment: Try watching the above one. It's best always to use a virtualenv. It's like your personal house but I 'm not sure if the above video uses virtualenv.

Comment: Hmm I remember following COrey Schafer videos too when figuring out how to deploy the site and I don't think he used virtualenv, but that was a different video... I think it was for flask, but he used Linode so I still used it. Anyway, will follow this video now, thanks.

Comment: This guy is the best for tutorials when it comes to python.Otherwise others just skip the steps, the errors and just try to refrain from the errors that you suffer.

Comment: Can you share your `requirements.txt`'.

Comment: @Kaushal Please see my edit. Ty.

Comment: @VisheshMangla I followed Corey Schafer video with a new linode server, and used virtualevn this time, but it is still the same. No idea whats wrong.

Comment: How are you sure that this issue is because transformer library is not importing? Do you have any logs? It could be because of some other reason as well.

Comment: hmm, maybe others can help. Are you sure your virtualenv's python is getting used? Are you sure you didnt skip steps?

Comment: @VisheshMangla Thanks for your help and recommending Corey Schafer's video, I learned a lot from it regardless. :)

Comment: Upvote him and make contribution to his channel if you want to support channels like these.No advertisement intend.

Comment: Yes, I'm already subscribed to him :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you just have to create or update your *requirements.txt* file.

Here is the command : `pip freeze > requirements.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/514251)

> Some third party packages for Python which use C extension modules, and this includes scipy and numpy, will only work in the Python main interpreter and cannot be used in sub interpreters as mod_wsgi by default uses.

`transformers` library uses numpy, so you should force the WSGI application to run in the main interpreter of the process by changing apache config:

```
## open apache config
$ nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

## add this line to apache config
 WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

## restart apache
$ systemctl restart apache2
```

now it works!!

for more information visit the link above.